# $setViewValue with object copy performance

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive for a toggle button derived from the btnRadio of Angular UI. Instead of just using a simple model with toggled values I have modified it to accept a model which is a "global" object used by all the directive instances - I pass the key to the directive in order to extract the particular data. In my directive I search through this object and handle it from there. All works great but I have a performance concern. In the directive I have to make a copy of the model (per Angular docs) and reapply that to my view using ngModelController.$setViewValue. This model can contain 100's of entries. And this directive can appear a few dozen times. Is there a potential  for some memory leak if I create copies of the this large object in every directive?

Here's the directive:

```
app.directive('btnChoice', function () {
  return {
    require: ['btnChoice', 'ngModel'],
    controller: 'ButtonsController',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
      var buttonsCtrl = ctrls[0], ngModelCtrl = ctrls[1];

      function getChoice() {
        var val = scope.$eval(attrs.btnValue);
        console.log(val);
        return (angular.isDefined(val) && ngModelCtrl.$modelValue && ngModelCtrl.$modelValue[val]) ? ngModelCtrl.$modelValue[val] : false;
      }

      //model -> UI
      ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
        element.toggleClass(buttonsCtrl.activeClass, angular.equals(getChoice(), attrs.btnChoice));
      };

      //ui->model
      element.bind(buttonsCtrl.toggleEvent, function () {
        if (!element.hasClass(buttonsCtrl.activeClass)) {
          scope.$apply(function () {
            var ev = attrs.btnEvent;
            var c = attrs.btnChoice;
            var v = scope.$eval(attrs.btnValue);
            scope.$emit(ev, { model: v, value: c });
            ngModelCtrl.$modelValue[v] = c;
            // The line below worries me
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(angular.copy(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue););
            ngModelCtrl.$render();
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Here's the view:

```
 <div class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="$attendances" btn-event="attend" btn-choice="yes" btn-value="item.id">Yup</label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="$attendances" btn-event="attend" btn-choice="maybe" btn-value="item.id">Maybe</label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="$attendances" btn-event="attend" btn-choice="no" btn-value="item.id">Nope</label>
</div>
```

The model looks like:

```
var model = {
  '7612tas337213': 'yes',
  '7q23423h1237s': 'maybe
}
```